# div sorting with javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-8

This is a 2 part question.

1)I'm looking to sort divs by alphabetical order, which someone helped me to do and it works on Firefox and Chrome, but it doesn't work in IE8 because you have to shim the arrays and I have no idea how to do that. A buddy told me you can use Jquery and it would work in all browsers. So is there a way to sort the divs in alphabetical order with Jquery so I don't have to shim the arrays (which I have no idea how to do) or is there a javascript that has an IE8 solution?

I'm new to coding so a working example would be very helpful. Thank you!

Here are the javascript and the divs:

```js
var VanillaRunOnDomReady = function() {
var main = document.getElementById( 'main' );

[].map.call( main.children, Object ).sort( function ( a, b ) {
    return a.id > b.id;
}).forEach( function ( elem ) {
    main.appendChild( elem );
});
}
var alreadyrunflag = 0;

if (document.addEventListener)
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
        alreadyrunflag=1; 
        VanillaRunOnDomReady();
    }, false);
else if (document.all && !window.opera) {
    document.write('<script type="text/javascript" id="contentloadtag" defer="defer" src="javascript:void(0)"><\/script>');
    var contentloadtag = document.getElementById("contentloadtag")
    contentloadtag.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if (this.readyState=="complete"){
            alreadyrunflag=1;
            VanillaRunOnDomReady();
        }
    }
}

window.onload = function(){
  setTimeout("if (!alreadyrunflag){VanillaRunOnDomReady}", 0);
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
<div id="danger">7</div>
<div id="angel">1</div>
<div id="enormous">8</div>
<div id="correct">4</div>
<div id="forever">11</div>
<div id="backyard">2</div>
</div>
```

2) Is there a script that flips the order around (ei from a - z to z - a) when a certain date passes. For example, from the first of the month to the 15th of the month, I want this script from part 1 to be in alphabetical order (a - z) but from day 16 to the 31, the opposite (z - a). Do I need a script to change the other script or can be implemented in the first script above?

Comment: IE11 doesn't seem to sort this. Looks like a bug.

Comment: Correction, IE seems to implement this differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the sorting for IE (all versions), plus I added a sorting mechanism for IE8. (The IE8 solution should work in all browsers though).

```js
    var VanillaRunOnDomReady = function() {
    var main = document.getElementById( 'main' );

 if (Array.prototype.map && Array.prototype.forEach)
 {
  //this funky bit can be done by all modern browsers. Sorting fixed for IE.
    Array.prototype.map.call( main.children, Object ).sort( function ( a, b ) {
  if (a.id > b.id) return  1;
  if (a.id < b.id) return -1;
  return 0;
  }).forEach(function(element){
     main.appendChild(element);
  });
 }
 else
 {
        //this bit uses old fashioned coding. No querySelectors and fancy array functions.
  var allDivs = main.childNodes;
  var store = [];
      
        //push all divs into an array
  for (var i = 0; i < allDivs.length; ++i)
  {
   if (allDivs[i].nodeType != 3 && allDivs[i].tagName && allDivs[i].tagName.toLowerCase() == "div")
   {
    store.push(allDivs[i]);
   }
  }
  
        //sort the array
  store.sort(function ( a, b ) {
  if (a.id > b.id) return  1;
  if (a.id < b.id) return -1;
  return 0;
  });
  
        //reset the sorted divs.      
  for (var i = 0; i < store.length; ++i)
  {
   main.appendChild(store[i]);
  }
 }
 }
 var alreadyrunflag = 0;

    if (document.addEventListener){
        document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
            alreadyrunflag=1; 
            VanillaRunOnDomReady();
        }, false);
 }
    else if (document.all && !window.opera) {
   VanillaRunOnDomReady();
   alreadyrunflag = 1;
 }

 

    window.onload = function(){
      setTimeout("if (!alreadyrunflag){VanillaRunOnDomReady}", 0);
    }
```

```html
    <div id="main">
    <div id="danger">7</div>
    <div id="angel">1</div>
    <div id="enormous">8</div>
    <div id="correct">4</div>
    <div id="forever">11</div>
    <div id="backyard">2</div>
    </div>
```

As for the second one:

I would just divide the amount of divs into two groups. One to the fifteenth and one from the sixteenth. Then sort them appropriately and append them to the `main div`.

Comment: it is working great! Thank you for your quick reply. Now for the second one, I'm not sure if I understand what you mean. The reason I was asking if there was a script to flip the order automatically is because I wanted to create one set of divs and not have to duplicate them. Is there a way to incorporate it on the code above or is it a totally different script all together?

Comment: I just used an if or else statement before the code you provided and helped with the sorting of the dates. Thanks again!